# Code for drawing two intersecting lines and the acute angle between them

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the code for two intersecting lines. I know the code that I use to draw lines `$\ell$` and `$k$` is bad. I am sure that is the reason that the labels `$\ell$` and `$k$` are not in the right places.  I want `$\ell$` to be to the above and left of upper arrowhead and `$k$` to be to the right and below the right arrowhead. (Line `$\ell$` is the more upright line.)

Point `$P$` should be at the intersection of the two lines. It is not. Point `$A$` should be on `$\ell$` and point `$B$` should be on `$k$`. They are not. `$\angle APB$` should be marked with an arc.  The arc is not centered at `$P$`.  The line segments `$\overline{AP}$`, `$\overline{BP}$`, and `$\overline{AQ}$` should be labeled with `$r$`, `$x$`, and `$y$`, respectively, in the middle of arrows. The arrows are all there but shifted.

The diagram is a mess.  I think that with an appropriate code for the two lines, the new code would give the diagram that I want. (It is a diagram for defining the sine and cosine functions for acute angles.)  Please add `"$\theta$"` to the angle in the diagram.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style={
  fill,
  circle,
  inner sep=1.5pt
  }
]
\path (80:3) coordinate (a) (20:3.5) coordinate (b) (0:0) coordinate (P);
\path (-70:1) coordinate (e) (-160:1) coordinate (f) (0:0) coordinate (P);
\path (80:2) coordinate (A) (20:2.5) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (P);
\draw[<->] node [at start, left]{$\ell$} (a) -- (e);
\draw[<->] node [at start, right]{$k$} (b) -- (f);

\node[dot,label={left:$P$}] at (A) {};
\node[dot,label={below:$B$}] at (B) {};
\node[dot,label={left:$P$}] at (P) {};
\node[dot,label={right:$P$}] at (B) {};

\draw (A)
-- (P) node [at start, below left]{$A$}
-- (B) node [at start, right]{$B$};
\coordinate (Q) at ($(P)!(A)!(B)$);
(P) node [at start, left below]{$P$};
(Q) node [at start, right]{$Q$};
\draw[purple!70!black,dashed] (A) -- (Q);
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Q,P);

\draw[|<->|] ($(P)!7mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$r$} ($(A)!7mm!-90:(P)$);
\draw[|<->|] ($(P)!7mm!90:(B)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$x$} ($(B)!7mm!-90:(P)$);
\draw[|<->|] ($(Q)!7mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$y$} ($(A)!7mm!-90:(Q)$);
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=2mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=2] {angle = B--P--A};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you please at least clean up the code a bit? You definitely know that there is no such thing as `left below` and remove the parts that you already know how to do such as labeling etc. I don't understand anything from the resulting picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to get out of that "all chaos" I got this:

[image]

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]

\path (80:3) coordinate (a) (20:3.5) coordinate (b) (0:0) node[dot,label=below left:$P$]{} coordinate(P)(-100:1)coordinate (e) (-160:1) coordinate (f)(80:2) node [dot,label=above left:$A$]{} coordinate (A) (20:2.5) node [dot,label=below:$B$]{} coordinate (B) ($(P)!(A)!(B)$) coordinate [label=below:$Q$](Q);
\draw[<->]  (a) node [above left ]{$l$} -- (e);
\draw[<->]  (b) node [below right]{$k$} -- (f);

\draw[purple!70!black,dashed] (A) -- (Q);
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Q,P);

\draw[|<->|] ($(P)!3mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$r$} ($(A)!3mm!-90:(P)$);
\draw[|<->|] ($(P)!-3mm!90:(B)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$x$} ($(Q)!-3mm!-90:(P)$);
\draw[|<->|] ($(Q)!-3mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$y$} ($(A)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=9mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle = B--P--A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for decoding that mess. There is one correction. $x$ denotes the length of $\overline{PQ}$. Please correct it for the other members of this site.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: causes error with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. in that case use `pic text=$\theta$` instead of the quotes library.